# Windows 7 HDD with a BSOD on boot, not detected when connected as non-boot drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bsod

I've just installed a new SSD into a Dell Vostro - I first tried cloning the old HDD onto the new SSD, then switched the boot priority but it wouldn't boot from the SSD and fell back to the HDD.

So I booted from the recovery DVD and did a proper fresh install of Windows 7 onto the SSD, and left the HDD connected as a second drive.

Updated the BIOS boot order and my fresh SSD install loads within a few seconds, wonderful.

BUT now I can't see the old HDD in My Computer or even in the Disc Management tool.

I've switched the boot order back, but I get a BSOD on boot with the HDD.

I did try to switch the HDD to I: and the SSD to C: earlier in the process, but that didn't help and maybe that caused the BSOD.

Anyway I stuck the HDD in a USB enclosure and booted from the SSD again - now Windows 7 loads fine and I can browse the old HDD via USB without a problem.

I have no desire to boot from the HDD again, just want the old files and to keep it as storage.

Should I just delete the windows folder?

Comment: Sorry, just connected but disabled boot in the BIOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - the old HDD had an 30GB SSD set as it's cache via RAID.

I had to switch from RAID to AHCI in the BIOS, which causes another BSOD unless you update the registry first, which can be done using the guide from the following link:

http://www.overclock.net/t/1227636/how-to-change-sata-modes-after-windows-installation